# '\n' not sending file.write() to next line using seek() while looping

Tags: python, text-files

My problem is a simple one (too simple...). I am opening a new text file via `with` and attempting to write each row from a `pandas.DataFrame` to the file. Specifically, I'm trying to place column entries at very specific character positions on each line, as that is the required format for the people receiving my file.

**df** represents my `pandas.DataFrame` in the code below.

```
with open(os.path.join(a_directory_var, 'folder/myfile.txt'), 'x') as file:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        file.seek(1)
        file.write(row['col1'])
        file.seek(56)
        file.write('|')
        file.seek(61)
        file.write(row['col2'])
        file.seek(76)
        file.write('|')
        file.seek(81)
        file.write('col3')
        file.seek(96)
        file.write('|\n')
```

**Expected Output:**
I expected my last line to place a pipe, and send `file` to the next line with '\n', so that the next call to `file.write()` would begin writing entries to the next line.

**Actual Output:** Characters from each row being written over themselves on the first line, over and over again. It may be worth noting that the resulting text file *does* have an empty second line.

In summation, I'm simply trying to write to a line, go to the next, write to that line, go to the next, etc, etc.

Comment: `seek` does not know about lines. `seek(1)` takes you to 2nd byte of the file, not 2nd character of the line. You are thus constantly overwriting the start of the file.

Comment: you keep seeking to the same place in the file so you will write to the same place over and over in the loop, the question is: what were you hoping to achieve with seeking like that? using `'x'` tells me you are creating a new file which means the file is empty - so if you write to position 1 and position 56 in the file (which by the way skips position 0... ) what will the bytes inbetween be?

Comment: Why don't you write formatted lines? E.g. `file.write("{:56s}|    {:15s}|...".format(row['col1'], ...))` or similar?

Comment: Create a full line from your dataframe, append it to the end of the file. Do it in the loop.

Comment: Finally, note that files typically aren't byte-addressable; you aren't saving on I/O by writing a few bytes here and there. What's really happening is that your targeted writes are updating a buffer in memory, and an entire block (of some OS-specified size) of original and updated bytes is actually written to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to write a fixed-width column format, with additional `|` characters as separators. As that is not a simple option in Pandas (such as `df.to_csv(fp, sep='|'`), you have to iterate over the rows, as you do, and write them one by one. But don't write each part separately: format the lines using Python formatting.

For example, something like this should get close to what you want (give or take a slight offset due to me not counting properly):

```
sep = "|"
with open(os.path.join(a_directory_var, 'folder/myfile.txt'), 'x') as fp:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        fp.write("{:56s}{:15s}{:15s}{:15s}{:15s}\n".format(
            row['col1'], sep, row['col2'], sep, row['col3'], sep)
```